# Remove characters between two characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am having a problem with trying to remove text between two characters. 
I want to remove all text between `=` and `,`. Here is sample code I am trying to apply this to.

```
    "Y = Yellow,  W = White,  B = Blue,  R = Black Out"
```

What i want to do is have the above change to this.

```
    "Y W B R"
```

or this but the above is prefered.

```
    "Y W B R = Black Out"
```

Here is what i am trying.

```
        string input = "Y = Yellow,  W = White,  B = Blue,  R = Black Out";
        string regex = "(\\=.*\\,)";
        string output = Regex.Replace(input, regex, "");
```

Here is what gets shown

```
    "Y R = Black Out"
```

I know i am doing something wrong. This is my first time using Regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `*` is greedy with regular expressions. Therefore, everything from the first `,` to the last `=` is grabbed. Use `*?` to use a non-greedy match:

```
string regex = "=.*?,";
```

To get rid of the last value, you can do this:

```
string regex = "=.*?(,|$)";
```

Comment: that gets this outcome.     "Y W B R = Black Out"   Is there any way to get this outcome     "Y W B R"  ?

Comment: Yes, you can do `string regex = "(\\=.*?\\(,|$))";` to match either a comma or the end of the string.

Comment: Also, you have more escapes and parentheses than are required. See my update.

Comment: Perfect that works great. Thanks a lot. Will accept answer when it allows me.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use regex:

```
string result = string.Join(" ", input.Split(',')
                                 .Select(p => p.Split('=')[0].Trim()));
```

Comment: That works also. Which one is better to use though ? Also sorry but i have to mark Jacobs answer as the one that solved this. He answered first.