# Trim Characters between two characters

Tags: c#, trim

I am having the following string,

**Hdw.Instrument.Pins(\"PinName\").PSets(\"SignalName\").Apply()**

I need to trim the above string and the output should be as follows,

**Hdw.Instrument.Pins.PSets.Apply**

I need to remove the characters between '()' along with the paranthesis.

Comment: What you tried so far? any attempt?

Comment: https://regex101.com/ use this to test your regex

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006135/remove-characters-between-two-characters

Answer (score 2):

```
string text = "Hdw.Instrument.Pins(\"PinName\").PSets(\"SignalName\").Apply()";
string t = Regex.Replace(text, "(\\(\"[^()]*\"\\)|\\(\\))", string.Empty);
```

Regex.Replace method works for this.
You just need to write the correct regular expression.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The above code leads to the output as Hdw.Instrument.Pins.Apply. It's missing .Psets.

Comment: RegEx. Just what a beginner needs. https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: @John. Now it looks like Hdw.Instrument.Pins.Psets.Apply(). The parenthesis is not removed at the end.

Comment: @Neil But OP's scenario is a reasonable one in which to use regular expressions. It's not complicated and the expression remains easy to understand.

Comment: @Rayner Change the replace to `(text, @"(\(("".*?"")?\))", string.Empty)` (my mistake before, sorry)

Comment: The regular expression not correct.  Another one: (\\(\"[^()]*\"\\)|\\(\\))

Comment: ""(\\(\"[^()]*\"\\)|\\(\\))"" is not complicated?  Ha ha.  Funniest thing I've read today.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not going to write the code for you, but here's a clue:

## 1 Find the position of the first bracket (string.IndexOf).

## 2 Find the position of the last dot (string.LastIndexOf).

## 3 Remove the characters between those 2 positions (string.Remove).

Comment: [Are you sure that's the right solution?](https://rextester.com/LEF89610)

Comment: It's closer than the OP has got.

Comment: OP, if you decide to go with a string manipulation solution, I advise you to substitute #2 with [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_Int32_) of IndexOf.